# Почему не вызывается конструктор копирования?

Tags: ооп, c++

Есть такой класс:

```
class TFoo {
public:

    TFoo( int a ): a( a ) {
        cout << "Ctor with a = " << a << endl;
    }

    TFoo( const TFoo & ){
        a = 666;
        cout << "Copy ctor" << endl;
    }

private:
    int a;
};
```

Я пытаюсь создать его экземпляр таким способом:

```
    TFoo f = TFoo( 2 );
```

Думаю что должно быть выведено

Ctor with a = 2
Copy ctor

Но вместо этого получаю

Ctor with a = 2

Почему так происходит, ума не приложу.

Answer (score 6):

По стандарту, компилятор имеет право выбрасывать промежуточный конструктор копирования, даже если он имеет побочные эффекты. Это называется [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Вот [обсуждение на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12953127/276994) со ссылкой на соответствующую часть стандарта.

Поэтому, кстати, конструктор копирования должен **лишь копировать** и не менять данные (ну, может быть, ещё залогировать результат), поскольку он может быть выброшен оптимизатором.

---

Кстати, это единственная оптимизация, которая может «убирать» код с побочными эффектами.